# Copying a sheet to a new workbook but need to change the file type

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am looking to copy a worksheet into a new workbook and rename it.

I have found a code which is almost exactly what I need except it saves the file type has a *Microsoft Excel 97-2003 worksheet* is it possible to have it save as a *Microsoft Excel Worksheet*.

**Code Below:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyWorksheetsFomTemplate()
    Dim NewName As String
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If MsgBox("Copy specific sheets to a new workbook" & vbCr & _
    "New sheets will be pasted as values, named ranges removed" _
    , vbYesNo, "NewCopy") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False

         '       Copy specific sheets
         '       *SET THE SHEET NAMES TO COPY BELOW*
         '       Array("Sheet Name", "Another sheet name", "And Another"))
         '       Sheet names go inside quotes, seperated by commas
        On Error GoTo ErrCatcher
        Sheets(Array("Template")).Copy
        On Error GoTo 0

         '       Paste sheets as values
         '       Remove External Links, Hperlinks and hard-code formulas
         '       Make sure A1 is selected on all sheets
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.Cells.Copy
            ws.[A1].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            ws.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Cells(1, 1).Select
            ws.Activate
        Next ws
        Cells(1, 1).Select

         '       Remove named ranges
        For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
            nm.Delete
        Next nm

         '       Input box to name new file
        NewName = InputBox("Please Specify the name of your new workbook", "New Copy")

         '       Save it with the NewName and in the same directory as original
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & NewName & ".xls"
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    Exit Sub

ErrCatcher:
    MsgBox "Specified sheets do not exist within this workbook"

End Sub
```

I am an amateur at VBA but am slowly learning, so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you use `SaveCopyAs` you cannot alter the file type from that of the original document. You need to use `SaveAs` for that.

Comment: @Rory good point, I glossed over the "Copy" portion of `SaveCopyAs`.

Comment: thanks for this i changed `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & NewName & ".xls" ` to `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & NewName & ".xlsx"` and its worked a treat! thank you